# Cannot open GUI applications through remote SSH using my phone

Tags: command-line, ssh, transmission

Right now I'm sending this command through SSH from phone to my Ubuntu laptop.

```
echo SSHPASSWORD|sudo -S bash -c "export DISPLAY=:0"&&" + transmission-gtk
```

Non-graphical commands work fine. Printing out $DISPLAY didnt show anything on my phone, while it's 0 if I display it on my laptop. I've searched everywhere

This is what I get back.

```
09-14 00:15:53.295 6201-6201/david.sshapplication I/System.out: RESPONSE[sudo] password for david: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
09-14 00:15:53.295 6201-6201/david.sshapplication I/System.out: (transmission-gtk:27487): Gtk-[1;33mWARNING[0m **: cannot open display:
```

I however, cannot use ssh -X or something like that sadly. Just to make sure we're all on the same page I want to open the transmission program on my laptop, so I can just open it up from my bed without having to get up.

This is what I tried next:

```
echo SUDOPASS|sudo -S bash -s ts.sh
```

It appears to have run the script, but it doesnt actually open the app, the script set out to open. It opens if I run the script on my laptop.

Comment: Why do you need `sudo`? What is it with the weird quoting and `+` in `"export DISPLAY=:0"&&" + transmission-gtk`?

Comment: Dont you need sudo to execute bash scripts using SSH? THe weird quoting and + are because it's Java code. I'm sending this command using Java code, should look like this when it sends:

echo SSHPASSWORD|sudo -S bash -c "export DISPLAY=:0"&&transmission-gtk

Comment: no, think about it. You're already running a command via SSH (sudo in this case), so you can run commands via SSH. So why use sudo? Also you don't need bash or export. Just `env DISPLAY=:0 transmission-gtk` could replace your entire command

Comment: Its an exec type SSH, so I'm basically running 1 command and parsing its output in 1 session. If that matters. Do I really not need sudo?

Comment: what exactly do you think sudo is doing for you here? And why do you think you couldn't do whatever that is without sudo?

Comment: Because I'm dumb. Your thing worked obviously. Like whenever I execute a command on my laptop, it asks me for sudo pass, I input it and then it works. Why does that not happen with ssh?

Comment: can't say without more info. You might want to post a new question about that, including which commands you have to run with sudo and what happens when you run them without sudo.